# fetch data from localhost object error happening

Tags: json, fetch

Hi I create a backend and get it on the localhost as the picture:
[image]

And I fetch it in codepen,but it does not work.

```
  fetch(`localhost:5000/products`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Like this link:https://codepen.io/nutkin/pen/MWpMzMv?editors=0012

Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: Maybe you should add `http://` to address...

Comment: still not working,thanks and is there any other way to try?@Cássio Lacerda

Answer (score 0):

Hi after I install `Moesif Origin & CORS Changer by Moesif` in firefox extension,it works.Some backend do not support sharing data.